# Too large space after single quotation mark (’) U+2019 with zxjatype package

Tags: fonts, typography, languages, japanese

I have in my text just some words in Japanese and a use the `zxjatype` and the  `zxjafont` packages to get a rendering for Japanese fonts. But the problem is all the occurrences of the single quotation mark (*’*) is followed by a too large blank space.

So, with the following MWE…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}
\begin{document}

\section{日本語}
Machin
お早う

l’orem

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

I get this rendering:

[image]

I add that I can’t replace the `’` character with the `'` one. I really need to use `U+2019`.

So, how can I delete the blanc space after the quotation mark?

---

Update: I need to use `U+2019` specially.

Comment: I get no space with `l'orem` (straight quote instead of U+2019). Apparently, `zxjatype` assumes that there is a transition between Latin and Japanese at U+2019.

Comment: Yes, with `'` it work correctly, but I really need to use `’` because it is related to other thinks.

Comment: I added another workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character U+2019 apparently implies a transition to Japanese. It's not clear what rule is followed, but spaces are added at transitions; moreover the character U+2019 in IPAMincho has the same width as kana characters, resulting in very wide space.

This doesn't happen when `'` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}

\begin{document}

\section{日本語}

Machinお早うMachin

l’orem

l'orem

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't read Japanese, so I can't know whether this has adverse effects:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}

\XeTeXcharclass`’=\XeTeXcharclass`A

\begin{document}

\section{日本語}

Machinお早うMachin

l’orem

l'orem

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that exactly what I was searching. So there is a similar hack for `—` (`U+2014 EM DASH`) character? It seam having also a strange behavior with `zxjafont`. Or have I to open a new tread?

Comment: Since `zxjatype` treats U+2019 as a Japanese character, the font is switched and the spacing is tuned. The package provides a command `\textrawen` and `rawentext` environment, which disable these processes and output characters using Latin character font. They are explained [here](http://zrbabbler.sp.land.to/zxjatype.html) by the package author (unfortunately in Japanese).

Comment: `\textrawen` may be best used with your `newunicodechar` package, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have some time now, so I'd like to post my comment on egreg's answer as my own with some additional information.

As egreg guesses, U+2019 is considered to be a Japanese character and the following adjustments are carried out:

- Switching to Japanese font
- Insertion of a space between CJK and Latin characters

If you want to disable these adjustments, `\textrawen` provided by `zxjatype` is the way to go. I think this is safer than using a low-level primitive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}
\begin{document}

\section{日本語}
Machin
お早う

l’orem
l\textrawen{’}orem

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

[image: difference b/w w/ and w/o \textrawen]

If you don't want to use `\textrawen` every time you write `’` and all the `’` in your document can safely be assumed to be a Latin character, you can use the [`newunicodechar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}
\newunicodechar{’}{\textrawen{’}}
\begin{document}

\section{日本語}
Machin
お早う

l’orem

\textsf{こんにちわ}

\end{document}
```

[image: example of newunicodechar]

By the way, the space between "Machin" and "お早う" is different in OP's code and egreg's code. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zxjatype}
\usepackage[ipa]{zxjafont}
\xeCJKsetup{
  CJKecglue =
    { \hspace { 1em } }
    % initially set to \hspace { 0.25em plus 0.15em minus 0.05em } by zxjatype.
}
\begin{document}
Machin%
お早う
Machin
\end{document}
```

[image: difference b/w CJKecglue and whitespace]

The former space is the one between CJK and Latin characters as I noted above, and the latter is just a whitespace inserted by `\n`. Either one is OK, but please be sure to be consistent within one document.

---

As the names suggest, `zxjatype` is a package to *typeset* a Japanese document with XeLaTeX and `xeCJK` is to typeset a CJK document with XeLaTeX. Since you said

> I have in my text just some words in Japanese

in the question, you don't seem to be making an entire document in Japanese but to put several Japanese words in a Latin character document. In such cases, using `zxjatype` and `xeCJK` is an overkill or can even be harmful like this question.

If you just want to use a font that has Japanese glyphs, [`fontspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) is enough.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\mainja}{ipam.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\sansja}{ipag.ttf}
\newcommand*{\textsfja}[1]{{\sansja #1}}
\begin{document}
English, Français, and {\mainja 日本語} \par
\sffamily English, Français, and \textsfja{日本語}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample of fontspec]

Note that since spaces between CJK and Latin characters are not automatically inserted without `zxjatype`, you will need to use an ASCII whitespace to delimit words.

Comment: It’s much better, but is there a way to only activate CJK behavior only in a specific environment such as `\japanese` and keep the thinks out of this environment work normally?

Comment: @fauve Considering your purpose, I don't think you need `zxjatype`. Please refer to the update.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, instead of using `zxjatype` I resolve the problem with `xeCJK`.